# Get Controls from a DataTemplate inside a ListBox (or Panorama)

Tags: c#, silverlight, controls, windows-phone-7

I have a Panorama Control and inside it is a DataTemplate and inside the DataTemplate is an Image control. I want to get the Image control of the selected item to change it to something else. The xaml code is like this:

```
<controls:Panorama x:Name="FeedsPanorama" FontSize="20">            

            <controls:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Name="ItemDataTemplate">
                    <Grid d:DesignWidth="460" d:DesignHeight="700" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
                        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="118" Margin="2,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="167" x:Name="ImageThumbnail" Source="{Binding SummaryImageLink}" />                        
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:Panorama>
```

For example, every items will have their own images, but when it is selected, I will change the image to something else and then change back to it own image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the actual container using the ItemContainerGenerator of your control:

```
FeedsPanorama.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(currentDataObject);
```

Comment: It works for me to get the Grid out and then I still need to get the Image control using VisualTree. Anyway, thanks

Comment: Hi I have a listbox inside a panoramacontrol's datatemplate, how can I access it?